# Making a copy of record without edges

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a way to make a copy of an arbitrary OrientDB record without its edges? I modified an original command (from the docs) for copying records and added fetchplan to it, but it does not work (frankly speaking to me it looks like there's a problem parsing this particular command, but hopefully im wrong)

This one executes fine, but edges remain:

```
insert into Test from select from Test where @rid=#102:119 fetchplan in_*:-2 out_*:-2
```

This one gives an error:

```
insert into Test from (select from Test where @rid=#102:119 fetchplan in_*:-2 out_*:-2)
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.(SELECT FROM Test WHERE @rid = #102:119 FETCHPLAN in_*:-2 out_*:-2)
```

also tried smth like

```
insert into Test content (select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 out_*:-2') from Test where @rid=#102:119)
```

but that doesn't work either. Any thoughts? I'm on Orient 2.1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround you can use this javascript function with one parameter (id)

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var b=g.command("sql","select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 out_*:-2') as json from "+ id);
if(b.length>0){
    var query="insert into Test content " + b[0].getProperty("json") ;
    var myVertex=g.command("sql",query);
    g.commit();
    return myVertex;
}
```

Using the following command

```
select expand(result) from (select yourFunction(#102:119) as result)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I actually need that in a function and this is it :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to select all vertices (V) that have no incoming or outgoing edges:

```
select from (select @this, bothE().size() as n from V) where n = 0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i think there was a miscommunication here. I dont need to copy records that have no edges. I need to copy records without their edges - i.e. records with no strings attached so to say ))

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query and I have the same problem.
I solved it in this way:

```
insert into Test from select <property-name> from Test where @rid=#102:119
```

If you want use it with fatchplan try this:

```
insert into Test from select <property-name> from Test where @rid=#102:119 fetchplan in_*:-2 out_*:-2
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Michela

Comment: Michela, thanks, but unfortunately as you can see from my original post, `fetchplan` does not seem to work when it comes to copying records. And also I cannot use any `<property-name>` because i'd be copying arbitrary records (i.e. i dont know which attributes to expect, but i just need a record w/o edges)

Comment: Take a look to this link, maybe it could be useful: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/896

Comment: Michela, this is what I am looking for, but it's only in the milestones. Would be released with version 2.2 - 3.0, so that's not very useful now ))

Comment: Yes, I know I thought it would be useful show you that they are working on it.